# Using Rosyln CSharpScript.Create() without loading a DLL into the AppDomain

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Currently I execute a C# script as follows:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;

// ...

void RunScript(string myFile)
{
    string code = File.ReadAllText(myFile);
    var script = CSharpScript.Create(code, globalsType: typeof(MyContext));
    var scriptFunction = script.CreateDelegate();
    scriptFunction(myContextInstance).Wait();
}
```

However, each time a script is compiled and ran, a new DLL is loaded into the AppDomain.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
```

Example:

```
R*c906e0cf-ab67-4bed-819a-44600a796455#1-0, Version=0.0.0.0
R*c906e0cf-ab67-4bed-819a-44600a796455#2-0, Version=0.0.0.0
R*c906e0cf-ab67-4bed-819a-44600a796455#3-0, Version=0.0.0.0
```

This means that upon running a lot of scripts, one may experience **memory issues**. Is this true? Is there a way to prevent Roslyn to emit the DLL?

I know that you can't unload assemblies from the AppDomain.

Edit: [Support for collectible assemblies](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/306iqc/please_vote_for_the_clr_to_support_collectible/)

Comment: Why not create a new AppDomain, and then dispose of it when the script is done?

Comment: You are running different scripts every time (that is, `myFile` is different every time)?

Comment: The script files do change while the application is running, but not that often. Anyway, upon making 10 changes to 10 different scripts - and only compiling when the files change - there will be 90 unused DLLs in memory.

Comment: same problem here. AppDomain isn't supported on Core